# Cannot change style with set state conditionally based on type of element

Tags: reactjs, onclick, conditional-statements, use-state, react-state

I am trying to change colors of activity buttons when you click on a zone button with the changeActivityStyleBasedOnZone function. If for instance I click on a zone button that has type "concentration" I want to change the color of the activity buttons to the same color if they have type "concentration". Right now all the activity buttons change color when you click on a zone button. Right now I have the functionality that if you click on an activity button it changes color depending on the type of activity and this is something that I want to keep. How do I make only the buttons with the same type as the clicked zone button change colors without affecting the other activity buttons? I have also tried to test filtering the activities array on type and then mapping through the filtered array to set the state only on the filtered array but maybe this is the wrong approach or I am doing it wrong because the mapping doesn't seem to work.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Game = (activityType) => {
 const [activityStyle, setActivityStyle] = useState("activity");
 const [zoneClicked, setZoneClicked] = useState(false);
 const [clickedActivityIndex, setClickedActivityIndex] = useState(-1);

 const zones = [
    {id: 1, name: "Concentration", styleType: "concentration-zone", type: "concentration" },
    {id: 2, name: "Communication", styleType: "communication-zone", type: "communication"},
    {id: 3, name: "Collaboration", styleType: "collaboration-zone",  type: "collaboration"},
    {id: 4, name: "Chill Out", styleType: "chill-out-zone", type: "chillout"},
    {id: 5, name: "Camp", styleType: "camp-zone", type: "camp"}
   ]

 const activities = [
    {id: 1, name: "Code", type: "concentration"},
    {id: 2, name: "Teams Meeting", type: "communication"},
    {id: 3, name: "Make a phone call", type: "camp"},
    {id: 4, name: "Work shops with colleagues", type: "collaboration"},
    {id: 5, name: "Coffee break", type: "chillout"},
    {id: 6, name: "Lively discussions & brainstorming", type: "collaboration"},
   ]

 const changeActivityStyle = (activityType, index) => {
    setClickedActivityIndex(index);
     if (activityType === "concentration") {
         setActivityStyle("activity-concentration");
         setClickedActivityIndex(0) ;
       }
     if (activityType === "communication") {
         setActivityStyle("activity-communication");
     }
     if (activityType === "camp") {
         setActivityStyle("activity-camp");
     }
     if (activityType === "chillout") {
         setActivityStyle("activity-chill-out");
     } 
     if (activityType === "collaboration") {
         setActivityStyle("activity");
     }
     return;
 };

 const changeActivityStyleBasedOnZone = (zoneType) => {
     setZoneClicked(true);
     if (zoneType === "concentration") {
         const concentrationActivities = activities.filter(activity => activity.type === "concentration");
         concentrationActivities.map((ca) => {
            setActivityStyle("activity-concentration");
         }); 
        }
         
     if (zoneType === "communication") {
         setActivityStyle("activity-communication");
     }
     if (zoneType === "camp") {
         setActivityStyle("activity-camp");
     }
     if (zoneType === "chillout") {
         setActivityStyle("activity-chill-out");
     }
     if (zoneType === "collaboration") {
         setActivityStyle("activity");
     }
     return;
 }
return (
        <>
            <section className="header"><h2>Click on an activity box to see which area it belongs to</h2></section>
            <section className="game-area">
                <div className="activity-zone-container">
                    <div className="zone-container">
                        {zones.map((zone =>
                            <button 
                                className="zone" 
                                id={zone.styleType} 
                                key={zone.id}
                                zoneType={zone.type}
                                onClick={() => changeActivityStyleBasedOnZone(zone.type, 
                                 activityType)}
                                >
                                <p>{zone.name}</p>
                            </button>
                         ))}
                    </div>
                    <div className="activity-container">
                        {activities.map((activity, index) => 
                            <button 
                                className={clickedActivityIndex === index | zoneClicked === true ? activityStyle: 'activity'} 
                                onClick={() => changeActivityStyle(activity.type, index)} 
                                key={activity.id}
                                activityType={activity.type}>
                                <p>{activity.name}</p>
                            </button>
                            )}
                    </div>        
                </div>
            </section>
        </>
     );
   };
```

**CSS**

```css
#concentration-zone {
  background-color: orange;
}

#communication-zone {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#communication-zone p {
  color: black;
}

#collaboration-zone {
  background-color: #3260a8;
}

#chill-out-zone {
  background-color: pink;
}

#chill-out-zone p {
  color: black;
}

#camp-zone {
  background-color: green;
}

.activity {
  background-color: #3260a8;
  margin: 17px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 140px;
  height: 87px;
}

.activity-concentration {
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 17px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  width: 140px;
  height: 87px;
}

.activity-communication {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 17px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 140px;
  height: 87px;
}

.activity-chill-out {
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 17px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 140px;
  height: 87px;
}

.activity-camp {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 17px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  width: 140px;
  height: 87px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems here. I will try to address them in a sensible order and then provide example code at the end.

**Issues**

**1.** All the buttons are changing color because of this line:

```
className={clickedActivityIndex === index | zoneClicked === true ? activityStyle: 'activity'}
```

If `zoneClicked` is `true`, the class stored in `activityStyle` is applied to all buttons. Meanwhile, `zoneClicked` is set to `true` as soon as `changeActivityStyleBasedOnZone` is called:

```
const changeActivityStyleBasedOnZone = (zoneType) => {
     setZoneClicked(true);
...
}
```

**2.** `changeActivityStyle` and `changeActivityStyleBasedOnZone` conflict with each other.

They both change `activityStyle`, so the current value is applied to buttons with matching conditions and overrides the previous class value. This is just logically messy and makes it unclear what the point of `changeActivityStyle` is. My assumption is you want to apply a different style to the selected activity, independent of the selected zone style.

**3.** The `if` blocks in both `changeActivityStyle` and `changeActivityStyleBasedOnZone` are unnecessary and complicate the code.

This particular block is problematic. It applies the same value to `activityStyle` multiple times. I removed it completely from my solution, but I wanted to make you aware of that.

```
if (zoneType === "concentration") {
      const concentrationActivities = activities.filter(
        (activity) => activity.type === "concentration"
      );
      concentrationActivities.map((ca) => {
        setActivityStyle("activity-concentration");
      });
    }
```

**4.** `zoneType` and `activityType` are not valid html `button` properties.

Use `data-` attributes to create custom properties. The names must be all lowercases. e.g. `data-activity-type` and `data-zone-type`

---

**Solution**

As I said, I'm not totally sure of your goals, and I don't have your CSS, so you'll need to adjust this for your use case. That said, I think it will get you close.

Here's a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-river-nldcn?file=/src/Game.js:2186-2606) with the full example. I added a table to display the state values.

First, I changed `changeActivityStyle` and `changeActivityStyleBasedOnZone` as such:

```
const changeActivityStyle = (index) => {
    setClickedActivityIndex(index);
  };

  const changeActivityStyleBasedOnZone = (zone) => {
    setZoneClicked(zone);
    return;
  };
```

You'll notice this means `zoneClicked` now stores the whole `zone` object. So change the `useState` hook to this:

```
const [zoneClicked, setZoneClicked] = useState({});
```

And the zone button `onClick` gets changed to:

```
onClick={() => changeActivityStyleBasedOnZone(zone)}
```

Then I changed the activity button `className` like so:

```
<button
    className={
        `${activity.type === zoneClicked.type ? zoneClicked.styleType :"activity"} 
        ${clickedActivityIndex === index ? "selected" : ""}`
    }
    onClick={(e) => changeActivityStyle(index)}
    key={activity.id}
    data-activity-type={activity.type}
    >
```

Using template literals, we can apply two different classes based on two conditions, one related to the selected zone and one related to the selected activity.

Since `zoneClicked` now stores the whole zone, I just apply the selected zone's `styleType` as a class name.

If the selected activity index matches, I apply an additional class to highlight the selected button. In this case, the class just removes the border, but you could apply whatever style you want. Note the `!important` operator in the `selected` class - this ensures that the zone class doesn't override it if applied later.

Comment: This solution looks smooth. However, I find it hard to apply this to my code since styling for zones and activities differ in my case and I don't want the activities to get the zone styling as it is now. I just want to get the zone color.  Also the clicked activity should have a specific style based on the type of activity. If I click on an activity button that has type "concentration" it should become orange when clicked. I have updated my code with how my CSS looks if it makes sense. Do you have a suggestion on how I could achieve this?

Comment: You can just use a similar approach with the activity state - add a style property to the activity objects and store the whole activity on `changeActivityStyle`. Then update the `className` logic to apply them in the right order. I updated the CodeSandbox to give an example. I had to modify the CSS slightly to fit the logic.

Answer (score -1):

try this link and tell me if that is how the app is supposed to work.
https://growingillfatedrate.pskath1.repl.co/

here is the working code

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react';

const activities = [
    {id: 1, name: "Code", type: "concentration"},
    {id: 2, name: "Teams Meeting", type: "communication"},
    {id: 3, name: "Make a phone call", type: "camp"},
    {id: 4, name: "Work shops with colleagues", type: "collaboration"},
    {id: 5, name: "Coffee break", type: "chill-out"},
    {id: 6, name: "Lively discussions & brainstorming", type: "collaboration"},
];


 const zones = [
    {id: 1, name: "Concentration", styleType: "concentration-zone", type: "concentration" },
    {id: 2, name: "Communication", styleType: "communication-zone", type: "communication"},
    {id: 3, name: "Collaboration", styleType: "collaboration-zone",  type: "collaboration"},
    {id: 4, name: "Chill Out", styleType: "chill-out-zone", type: "chill-out"},
    {id: 5, name: "Camp", styleType: "camp-zone", type: "camp"}
];






const Game = () => {

 const [activityStyle, setActivityStyle] = useState("activity");
 const [zoneClicked, setZoneClicked] = useState(false);
 const [clickedActivityIndex, setClickedActivityIndex] = useState(-1);


 const changeActivityStyle = (activityType, index) => {
    setClickedActivityIndex(index);
     if (activityType === "concentration") {
         setActivityStyle("concentration");
         setClickedActivityIndex(0) ;
      }

     if (activityType === "communication") {
         setActivityStyle("communication");
     }
     if (activityType === "camp") {
         setActivityStyle("camp");
     }
     if (activityType === "chillout") {
         setActivityStyle("chill-out");
     } 
     if (activityType === "collaboration") {
         setActivityStyle("collaboration");
     }
     
     if (activityType === "chill-out") {
         setActivityStyle("chill-out");
     }
     return;
 };

 const changeActivityStyleBasedOnZone = (zoneType) => {
     setZoneClicked(true);
     if (zoneType === "concentration") {
        setActivityStyle("concentration")
      }
         
     if (zoneType === "communication") {
         setActivityStyle("communication");
     }
     if (zoneType === "camp") {
         setActivityStyle("camp");
     }
     if (zoneType === "chill-out") {
         setActivityStyle("chill-out");
     }
     if (zoneType === "collaboration") {
         setActivityStyle("collaboration");
     }
     return;
 }
return (
        <>
            <section className="header"><h2>Click on an activity box to see which area it belongs to</h2></section>
            <section className="game-area">
                <div className="activity-zone-container">
                    <div className="zone-container">
                        {zones.map((zone =>
                            <button 
                                className={zone.type} 
                                id={zone.styleType} 
                                key={zone.id}
                                zoneType={zone.type}
                                onClick={() => changeActivityStyleBasedOnZone(zone.type)}
                                >
                                <p>{zone.name}</p>
                            </button>
                         ))}
                    </div>
                    <div className="activity-container">
                        {activities.map((activity, index) => 
                            <button 
                                className={activityStyle == activity.type ? activityStyle: '' } 
                                onClick={() => { changeActivityStyle(activity.type, index) }} 
                                key={activity.id}
                                activityType={activity.type}>
                                <p>{activity.name}</p>
                            </button>
                            )}
                    </div>        
                </div>
            </section>
        </>
     );
};
```

and also the same repl link you can add your styles and test on your way.
https://replit.com/@pskath1/GrowingIllfatedRate?v=1

Comment: This works almost as I want except for when I click on the Workshop with colleagues button or the Lively discussions & brainstorming button both the buttons change color to orange instead of only the selected button.